# "dotnet build" on project targeting multiple frameworks is only building "netstandard2.0" and not generating nupkg file

Tags: .net, .net-core, msbuild, target-framework

I have a project that is targeting both `net472` and `netstandard2.0`.  When I build the project in VisualStudio, both frameworks are generated in the output directory and a `.nupkg` file is generated, as expected.

When trying to build the same project in the CLI with `dotnet build` it only builds the `netstandard2.0` project and not the `net472`.  Also, the `.nupkg` isn't generated (presumably because all targets aren't available, but I'm not sure).

I have other projects that are setup the same way as this project but only target `netstandard2.0` and these projects generate the `.nupkg` when using `dotnet build`.

How do I get dotnet to build the project with both frameworks and generate the .nupkg file?  From my understanding, `dotnet build` is supposed to build all targeted frameworks unless the `-f` switch is provided.

Here's a slightly modified version of the project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net472;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- .NET 4.7.2 only packages -->
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net472'">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" Version="5.2.7" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- All framework packages -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- Project references -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Various reference in here -->
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Additional info:

**dotnet --version:** 3.1.300

**msbuild -version:** 16.5.0.12403

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While looking for other build configurations that may causing this, I opened `Directory.Build.props` in my solution folder and noticed the following:

```
<!-- SDK Default Framework -->
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Because both `TargetFramework` and `TargetFrameworks` elements were both present in the final config, `dotnet build` must have been using the `TargetFramework` value and ignoring `TargetFrameworks`.

My solution was to remove the element from `Directory.Build.props` and add the element to each `.csproj` in the solution.

There is probably also a solution that would allow you to remove the `TargetFramework` element from the project that also uses `TargetFrameworks`, but I didn't spent much time looking for one.

Comment: You absolute legend. Thank you!